# BufferedWriter without try method IOException

Tags: java, try-catch, ioexception, bufferedwriter, writer

I know this topic has been discussed a lot and I have already read a lot of posts here about that, but I still seem to have trouble.

My problem is that I am also a beginner and I don't really understand how ĸwork and the try and catch function.

I have been trying to write to a file some string array, but it doesn't appear in there, nor the catch error is displayed in the console. I don't want to use the try method in this case, because when I am, I cannot use the variable declared for let's say BufferedWriter in other places, I am only restricted to the try method. Otherwise, I get a bug.

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class FileWrit  {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("testing.txt"))) {
            String[] anything = new String[3];
            writer.write("anything");
            anything[0] = "case1";
            anything[1] = "This is 1.5";
            anything[2] = "Case 3, i do not know how to count";
            for(String mem: anything) {
                writer.append(mem);
            }
            writer.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Idk when should this appear?");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, never ever swallow the exception like that and print a lame error message instead.  The exception has the information you want to see.  In most cases you just want to throw the exception, so add a `throws Exception` to the `main` method and get rid of the `catch` altogether.

Comment: Second, Java sometimes has weird ideas where files go.  You can resolve what is going on just by printing the full path.  Declare a file, `File("testing.txt")` and then print its absolute path: `System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());`  That will show you where the file is actually going.

Comment: Does the file not appear of it's empty ? maybe you're not looking to the good one, try System.out.println(new File("testing.txt").getAbsolutePath());

Answer (score 0):

For the "can't use it anywhere" part of your problem, you could declare the variable outside of the try catch block and only assign it inside. You can do a null check wherever else you want to use it to make sure there's no problems, or assign it another value in the catch block. Like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 BufferedWriter writer;
 String[] anything;
 try {
  writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("testing.txt"))) {
  anything = new String[3];
  writer.write("anything");
  anything[0] = "case1";
  anything[1] = "This is 1.5";
  anything[2] = "Case 3, i do not know how to count";
  for (String mem: anything) {
   writer.append(mem);

  }
  writer.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  writer = null;
  e.printstacktrace();
 }
}
}


if(writer != null){
       System.out.println(writer);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for maybe being annoying, but my lack fo knowledge in Java makes it difficult for me. I am trying to use this, I finally got something going, but I do not get the Exception thing, what does it do? And still, I am not sure, if I go out of the try function, (even if I do not do writer.close(); , I try to do writer.write("something"); and it seems I still get an IOException. Should you only write in a file using the try-catch function?

Comment: Yes, writing to a file should always be disclosed using try-catch blocks(or throws declaration, which I wouldn’t recommend to the main method). Declaring the variable outside is just so that you can access it, given that you saved your information within the try catch. In your example, you’re only using this object to write, so It might not matter as much. But yea, try-catch blocks are needed in pretty much every IO (read-write to files) operations. That is, just talking about IOExceptions. Take it as an if/else statement, in which you try and avoid the else part.

Answer (score 0):

try and catch it's use for managed the exception. try this code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class FileWrit  {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("testing.txt"))
            String[] anything = new String[3];
            writer.write("anything");
            anything[0] = "case1";
            anything[1] = "This is 1.5";
            anything[2] = "Case 3, i do not know how to count";
            for(String mem: anything) {
                writer.append(mem);
            }
            writer.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The System.err.println("Idk when should this appear?"); appear when you have an Exception in your try "an Error".